# How to add dynamically collections to SolrCloud

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

When I try to creat a new collection in my SolrCLoud I get the Error message

`Specified config does not exist in ZooKeeper:my_new_collection`

from the  [Apache Solr Reference Guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API) I learnd that the parameter 
`**collection.configName** must already be stored in ZooKeeper`
but how and when can I tell my ZooKeeper about the new config file when I am just about to create a new collection with a new config file?

Is there realy no example of adding collection to a SolrCore in the web? I only found tutorials for adding shards to nodes, but none for adding collections to a SolrCloud.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using embed zookeeper (which running at localhost:9983 ) . You need to upload configuration to zookeeper via zkcli.sh script.
For example:

> ./zkcli.sh -cmd upconfig -zkhost  localhost:9983 -confname
>   your_config_name  -confdir /path/to/your/config

If you are using solr version 5.x and running at cloud mode, you can specify step by step to create a fully functional collection, and then re-upload your custom configuration later.